# How to dynamically update an NSTreeController and NSOutlineView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

When an outlineViewItem is expanded -

```
 (void) outlineViewItemDidExpand:(NSNotification *)notification
```

-, I'm able to successfully add an object to the TreeController (log statements show the newly added object in the correct place of the hierarchy), but the OutlineView/UI isn't updating to reflect that insertion.

To no avail, I've used

- `[self.outlineView reloadItem:nil reloadChildren:YES]`,
- `[self.outlineView reloadData]`, and even
- `[self.outlineView setHidden:YES]` then
  `[self.outlineView setHidden:NO]`

to try to force reload the structure.

This is all done programmatically in Objective-C.

Comment: Do you use bindings or just `NSOutlineViewDataSource`-protocol methods?

Comment: I use bindings for Value, Outline View Content, and Index Path (NSOutlineView), and Content Array/Controller Content (NSTreeView).

The only delegate I use is: - (void) outlineViewItemDidExpand:(NSNotification *)notification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

6 hours later, I got it.

I needed to update the NSTreeController cache, which is achieved via the `rearrangeObjects` method.

So the answer to my question is:

```
[self.cloudDirectoryTreeController rearrangeObjects];
```